# What is wrong with this (vimscript) code?

Tags: vim

Does anyone know why this never doesn't work:

```
if !exists("g:removenumbchar")
  if a:type == "remove"
   let g:removenumbchar = "How many characters do you want remove at the end?"
  elseif a:type == "add"
   let g:removenumbchar = "How many characters do you want add at the end?"
  endif
endif  
let c = inputdialog(g:removenumbchar)
```

even if "a:type" value is correct, sometimes it shows the first sentence sometimes the second one.
I've never understood how this comes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `g:removenumbchar` will persist across calls to the function I assume this is in, so after you've called it once you'll get the same message every time regardless of what's in `a:type` on subsequent calls. Could that be what you're seeing?

Comment: yes that can be correct. Do you know how to avoid persistence?

Comment: Why are you using a global for this at all?

Comment: Good question. Always used global variables. When do I have to use a global variable and when not?

Comment: This may sound rather vague, but: Use a global variable when the information it stores needs to be global (because other functions need to get at it, it needs to persist across invocations, etc.) and not otherwise.

Comment: Thank you Gareth. I removed the "g:" before the variables and not it works fine.